# SQL Server: Error converting data type varchar to numeric for JavaTexfield

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I want to print 4 different values from my database table in 4 different Java Textfields when u click in the corresponding row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use String.valueOf(arg) to convert to string your values. Also if the values coming from your database are numeric, you might want to call getDouble or getFloat on your ResultSet object too. Don't forget to remove the casts in the query as you will tranform the values in the Java code instead, like this:

```
textFieldEröffnungspreis.setText(String.valueOf(rs.getDouble("Eröffnungspreis")));
```